# Java doesn't change look and feel when invoked from another class

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

I am new to java, I facing a problem while trying to change the look and feel of a java file when invoked from another class. I have two classes, `main.java` and `auth.java`. I have set the look and feel as nimbus in the `auth.java` file. When I try to invoke auth class from main.java(i have attached the code snippet below) the UI doesn't change. But when i use 
`public static void main(String[] args) in auth.java` and try to run that file individually the UI of the `jFrame` changes. Kindly let me know if there is a way to change the UI of a `jFrame` when called from another class. And is there any problem invoking the `jFrame` from `another class`, is that a good practice? because we are onto doing a big project and will require calling authentication frame once in a while, so any suggestion guys?
Thank you all in advance! :)

main.java:

```
package com.package.name;
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new auth();
    }
}
```

This is a section of my auth.java code:

```
package com.package.name;
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;

public class auth extends JFrame {
    public auth() {
        initComponents();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel ( "javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel" );
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                setVisible(true);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                pack();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Any error message ..?

Comment: no.. nothing, just the same old java laf when we try to call the auth class from main

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already called `initComponents` before changing the look at feel.  This will install what ever is the currently installed look and feel into those components.

Without having to go and instruct each component to update its UI, you could simply swap the installation of the look and feel with the `initComponents` method, for example...

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel ( "javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel" );
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
initComponents();
setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
pack();
```

Now, having said that.  You really should have been within the context of the EDT before you called the `auth` constructor and `auth` shouldn't really be making decisions about the Look and Feel.  What happens if you want to use this frame again with a different look and feel?

Instead could do something more like

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel ( "javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel" );
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                new auth();
            }
        });
    }
}

public class auth extends JFrame {
    public auth() {
        initComponents();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }
```

You should also consider taking a look through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), it will make your code much easier to read ;)

Comment: yeah i tried this method at first and that worked really nice. but i thought that we need to declare laf in the respective class itself.! :) thanks man. well another question, what if I have another class and wish to change it's LAF too? Just adding new class2(); to the main class will do?

Comment: Once you've installed the look and feel, all new components created will use, which is why you had the problem in the first place. So yes, just keep creating objects and they will use the same look and feel.